# How to Connect an ios App With mysql Database Using Python Instead of PHP

Tags: python, php, mysql, swift, python-3.x

I'm trying to access a mysql database inside an ios app and I would like to use python to read and write to the database when called from my app.

[PHP Code I would like to turn into a python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3gDn.png)

I am not sure how to write or read data from my application using mysql-connector.
I believe this is done with the $_POST[a]; but I am not sure how to get the same results using python.

I also have a sample of how I am trying to send data from my app to my database written in swiftui.

'''

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct CreateEventButton: View {
    @State private var isPresentedEvent = false
    @State private var eventid: Int = 0
    @State private var eventName: String = ""
    @State private var eventDescription: String = ""
    @State private var selectedStartTime = Date()
    @State private var selectedEndTime = Date()
    @Binding var annotationSelected: Bool

    func send(_ sender: Any) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://YOUR FILE PATH")! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let postString = "a=\(self.eventid)&b=\(self.eventName)&=c\(self.eventDescription)&=d\(self.selectedStartTime)&=e\(self.selectedEndTime)"

            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
                data, response, error in

                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }

                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
            }
            task.resume()

            self.eventName = ""
            self.eventDescription = ""
            self.selectedStartTime = Date()
            self.selectedEndTime = Date()
        }
    var body: some View {
      Button(action: {
            self.isPresentedEvent.toggle() //trigger modal 
        }, label: {
            Text("Create Event")})
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                .cornerRadius(50.0)
                .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentedEvent, content:{
            VStack{
                TextField("Event Name", text: self.$eventName).padding()
                TextField("Event Description", text: self.$eventDescription).padding()
                Form {
                    DatePicker("When your event starts: ", selection: self.$selectedStartTime, in: Date()...)
                }
                Form {
                    DatePicker("When your event ends:   ", selection: self.$selectedEndTime, in: Date()...)
                }
                HStack{
                Button(action: {
                    self.isPresentedEvent.toggle()
                    self.annotationSelected = false
                    self.eventid += 1
                    print("Start: \(self.selectedStartTime)")
                    print("End: \(self.selectedEndTime)")
                    //send()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Create Event")
                    })
                Button(action: {
                    self.isPresentedEvent.toggle()
                   }, label: {
                       Text("Cancel")
                   })
                }
                Text("Create Event Button (Non Functional)").padding()
            }
        } )
     }
}
```

'''

I am not sure what parameters to put in the sender function created here.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please look at the python/mysql connector basics https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp

Comment: @pc_ I'm fairly familiar with mysql-connector, but no tutorials show how to get data from an app, like the php script I have provided does. Do you know how I'd be able to send and recieve data from my app to the data base using mysql-connector and python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to receive POST requests from the SwiiftUI app, you need to run a python webserver like [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/).

#### 1. Create a python module (file) something like this:

`app.py`

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import make_response
import mysql.connector
from flask import request


server_name = "localhost"
username = "flask"
password = "flask"
dbname = "flask"

# Create and check connection
try:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=server_name,
        user=username,
        passwd=password,
        database=dbname
    )
    print("Connection OK")
except e:
    print("Connection failed: ", e)

mycursor = conn.cursor()


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    name = request.form['a']
    age = request.form['b']

    sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    val = (name, age)

    try:
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
    except e:
        print("Error: ", e)

    return make_response("Success!", 200)
```

#### 2. Make sure you have the necessary libraries installed:

```
pip install flask
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

You need to make sure your MySQL database is up and that you fill in the real credentials for the database in the code. (Default MySQL port = 3306)

#### 3. Start the flask development webserver

```sh
export FLASK_APP=app.py # OR set FLASK_APP=app.py (for Windows)
python -m flask run
```

Your server should start at: `http://localhost:5000`

Replace: `http://YOUR FILE PATH` with `http://localhost:5000/` in your swift code example and viola!

UPDATE: I tested this and it works. Here is the swiftUI code I generated in postman:

```swift
import Foundation

var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)

let parameters = "a=Lance&b=35"
let postData =  parameters.data(using: .utf8)

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost:5000/")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = postData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in 
  guard let data = data else {
    print(String(describing: error))
    return
  }
  print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
  semaphore.signal()
}

task.resume()
semaphore.wait()
```

Comment: when running python -m flask run, i get there error could not import "app". Do you know why this could be?

Comment: Are you running the flask command from the same directory as `app.py`?  I've now tested this and it does work. I had a few typos so you will need to follow the instructions again. I included a SwiftUI example as well.